# Launch App at OS X LoginWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have been trying to look into how to build an app window at the login screen.  Essentially in a way that Bootpicker works.  (see: http://www.myosxfreeware.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/bootpicker-1.jpg)  The Bootpicker project is closed and I have been spending hours to find the source code to study.

Does anybody have suggestions on what I need to do to start programming something like this?

Comment: You're interested in writing a [bootloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#Boot_loader).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, jones, but I am more interested in having an app that will load on the login window, not necessarily something that manages boot loading.  

My thought is to make another window that makes a user do something before being able to click on any user icons to start using the computer.

Answer (score 1):

BootPicker is a (mostly) normal Mac OS X application; the only really magic part is the LaunchAgent plist that it uses, which contains one special key:

```
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <string>LoginWindow</string>
```

I believe this is all that's necessary to make it launch at the login window.

Comment: Thanks, DuskWuff. I am making progress on opening an app via LaunchAgent plist.  For some reason it only goes as far as launching the menu bar of the app, not the app window itself (testing it with TextEdit.app).  I wonder if there is a window behavior properties for login screen?